# How can I fix 'Error 1004' when saving xlsx files from Access?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I have a simple script, yet no idea why it doesn't work.

Every time I run it, I get a Run Time Error 1004, "File cannot be accessed". Breaking on:

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilePath, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
```

I'm trying to overwrite the original file, as I need to correct it's internal formatting before I can import it into Access. The *.xlsx files in trying to import are missing the docProp folder. Sadly, I have no control over the system that generates them, so I can't fix that.

Full script:

```
Sub ReformatXLSX(strFilePath)

  Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
  Dim wb As Excel.Workbook

  Set appExcel = New Excel.Application
  Set wb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(strFilePath)

  wb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilePath, FileFormat:=xlWorkbookDefault
  wb.Close
  Set appExcel = Nothing
End Sub
```

Alternatively, if anyone knows how to import a file without TransferSpreadsheet I'd love to try that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The root cause is `SaveAs` **can't overwrite** the file.

A small improvement can be done with the code snippet. But it doesn't fix the problem.
The code is run with Access VBA. Please change Excel VBA const `xlWorkbookDefault` to its value (51) or `Excel.xlWorkbookDefault`.

```
wb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilePath, FileFormat:=51
```

---

You can get the value with Excel VBA Immediate window.

```
? xlWorkbookDefault
51
```

***OR***

Microsoft reference document:

> [XlFileFormat enumeration (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.xlfileformat?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)

Comment: Just tried that. Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error. :(

Comment: `wb.SaveAs Filename:=strFilePath` You can't save-as with same file name. Why not just using `wb.Save`? Are you going the change Excel file format? e.g transform xls to xlsx

Comment: @taller_ExcelHome: Your last comment (*"You can't save-as..."*) is the real answer to the question, you should put this into your answer.

Comment: This is the correction answer: SaveAs can't overwrite the file. I didn't expect Save to work and fix the missing docProps, but it sure did. Thank you! (Please edit your answer so I can mark it correct :) )